# Securing RABL gem (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, api, rabl

I'm using rabl gem

**show.rabl**

```
object @user
attributes :id, :name, :realname, :email
```

And i get

```
{"user":{"id":1,"name":"username","email":"mail@mail.com"}}
```

The problem is that anyone can see this info if they open http://website.com/users/user.json link

In my db each user after logging have unique auth_token field.

***Question is*** - I want to see this info only with this link -  http://website.com/users/user.json?auth_token=yLrUAxWB2szkvx9jBEGv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a check or work with some authorization gem like `cancan`.

Raw example so you can get a grasp (untested, wrote it on the phone...):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_token_if_json
  respond_to :html, :json

  def show
    @user = User.find params[:id]

    respond_with(@user)
  end

  private

  def check_token_if_json
    if params[:format] == 'json'
      raise "Access denied" and return unless params[:token] == 'my_required_token'
    end
end
```